# Reenabling default installation of trackpad on Dell XPS13

Tags: drivers, dell, trackpad

I have been having a lot of issues with the mouse cursor jumping all over the screen on my Dell XPS13 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

One of the things I did was install some "upstream" drivers using the guide from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/462830/340104.  Unfortunately, my trackpad experience has been much worse since applying this patch and now I need to basically hold my fingers vertically while touching the trackpad extremely lightly in order for them to not register as too wide.  Moreover, the trackpad cursor still continues to jump around the screen.  The trackpad on Win8 works perfectly though without any cursor jumping so it leads me to believe that it is in fact a driver issue.

The link within this answer (http://xps13-9333.appspot.com/#touchpad) says that if there are any problems, I can undo the changes by reinstalling the default synaptics driver:

```
aptitude install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

I did this and restarted but now the trackpad is still just as bad as after having applied the first patch.  Is there any way I can purge all trackpad settings/drivers/etc. and do a fresh install of the original drivers/settings?