# Touchpad became weird after installing updates on fresh installed Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

I'm having problem with my touchpad on my laptop. My laptop is Lenovo G40-70. When first I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop the touchpad is smooth. But after that I did software update from the internet right away.

After the software update, the touchpad becomes weird, really not smooth, hard to control. I tried reinstalling the OS twice. The touchpad becomes smooth again after reinstalling the OS so I guess it's not hardware problem, but it becomes weird again after the software update.

Answer (score 1):

I installed 14.04 on my asus r704a and had a lot of cursor issues. I found an answer here.

[Touchpad issue: jumping cursor while typing (Ubuntu 14.04), syndaemon don't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462135/touchpad-issue-jumping-cursor-while-typing-ubuntu-14-04-syndaemon-dont-help)

Andy wickert's response on answer number 4.

My issue is still present but not as bad as before. Perhaps this will help you too.