# Prevent cursor jumps with trackpad in dell xps-13 and ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad, dell, sputnik

The cursor tends to jump to the lower left corner of the screen when clicking on the trackpad in the xps-13 I purchased last December. I have found mentions to the issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593466/xps13-touchpad-issues-with-14-04-2) and [here](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg-devel/2014-June/042790.html), but both threads are 2+ years old.

Any more recent advice on how to deal with this will be most welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue on the XPS 15 9560. It only happens when I am moving the mouse with one finger and then clicking with another finger before lifting my first finger. Maybe it is due to broken gesture recognition? I don't have a solution at this point. You can use only one finger at a time, but that is very slow and annoying.

Comment: @Imran you describe my problem much more accurately than I did. And yes, it is quite annoying.