# How do I find out which touchpad driver is being used?

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I need to find out which touchpad driver is being used on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 so I can replace the one that comes with Ubuntu 18.04 (which is not working well).

I've tried `lshw` which lists hardware information but there is nothing about a touchpad I can see.

I've tried `lspci` and again nothing about a touchpad.

I've tried `xpinput list` which gives:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD Touchpad             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

but what does that mean? Is DLL0665:01 a driver?

I was expecting either `libinput` or `synaptics` to be listed somewhere as these names keep coming up when I search for linux touchpad drivers.

EDIT

As suggested, I've tried `lsmod` but no `synaptics` or `libinput` listed. I also tried `lsmod | grep hid` which gives:

```
hid_multitouch         20480  0
intel_hid              16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  3 dell_wmi,intel_hid,intel_vbtn
mac_hid                16384  0
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  2 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch
```

Comment: Do either of the two appear in: `lsmod` ?

Comment: @chili555 and there i was makign an answer :=)  @david: DLL means Dell so not a driver but an identification. The important part is behind it: vendor id 06CB and device ID 76AD . In older topics you can see people need to `blacklist i2c_hid` https://askubuntu.com/questions/593466/xps13-touchpad-issues-with-14-04-2 but wait for chili555 since that instruction is very old ;-)

Comment: Of course, as @Rinzwind suggests, also look for *i2c_hid* or any other *hid* in `lsmod`.

Comment: @chili555 edited question with result of `lsmod`

Comment: `lsmod` shows kernel drivers.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131432/which-driver-is-handling-my-touchpad

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run

```
xinput list-props 11
```

and you will see which **userspace** driver is used (libinput, or synaptics).

`11` is the touchpad id from `xinput list`.

It was not quite clear which driver are you asking about: kernel or userspace.

Comment: `xinput list-props 11` shows **Synaptics** driver is being used. Now I need to go and learn the difference between kernel and userspace drivers!

Comment: You can ask a question regarding the two drivers for input devices. It can be a good one.

Comment: The command shows "libinput" in the beginning of most properties, so I think my device is using that.

Comment: What exactly determines which driver is used? If names of some properties start with "Synaptics", e.g. "Synaptics Edges", does it mean that Synaptics driver is definitely used?

Comment: This is correct. If you see synaptics in properties, then synaptics is used.

Comment: I got nothing that shows either Synaptics of libinput. On MacBook with Ubuntu 16.04 I got `Device 'Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: ...`