# Disable touchpad while typing do not work

Tags: 16.04, dell, touchpad, synaptics, xps

In my laptop function to disable touchpad while typing is not working by default neither using running syndaemon with custom configuration.

gnome-settings-daemon run syndaemon as `syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R`. This configuration completely do nothing.

Any options for syndaemon do nothing. With\out `-R`, with\out `-t` etc.

Configuration is

- dell XPS 15
- Ubuntu 16.04
- i3wm

Comment: This thread here solved my problem: http://askubuntu.com/a/723954/585274

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution was to add in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
blacklist i2c_designware-platform
```

And reboot the system. After that `syndaemon` works fine.

Comment: It really does work, bro. You are really amazing. Why is this happening? BTW, ubuntu 16.04 really has lots of bugs, I still cannot poweroff my system.

Comment: It works, but I can't use my touchpad gestures now :(