# Cursor jumps on Dell XPS 15 running Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: touchpad, dell

I have a Dell XPS 15 9560 running Ubuntu 17.04, and the cursor jumps to the bottom of the screen when I am moving the pointer with one finger and then I click near the bottom of the touchpad with another finger before lifting my original finger.

I have tried the following, none of which fix the problem:

- Disable Tap to click
- Disable Two finger scroll
- Install either or both of xserver-xorg-input-libinput and xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
- Enable and narrow palm detection as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/508030/6419)

I didn't get very far with just libinput though, because my keyboard did not work at all.

This issue might be mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462135/touchpad-issue-jumping-cursor-while-typing-ubuntu-14-04-syndaemon-dont-help) or [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1574667) but I can't be sure if it's the same because no one mentions the two-finger nature of my problem.

The only workaround I have is to only use one finger on the touchpad at a time, but this is very slow and cumbersome.

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**UPDATE:** This was a hardware issue. I contacted Dell support and they ran some tests to determine the touchpad was defective.