# How can I disable touchpad while typing in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, system-settings, ubuntu-gnome

I want the touchpad to get disabled while typing.

Opening the system configuration and selecting "Pointing Devices" I can change only very basic settings, namely the primary and secondary button assignment, double click speed and cursor movement speed.

So, let's google...

I have found [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#Disabling_Touchpad_while_Typing). Further details about reasons or possible fixes are missing.

Some work-arounnds that I have found doesn't work for me. My system doesn't seem to load synaptics driver:

If type `synclient` I get `Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`.

I have also installed synaptiks, but at run it says that it can't find any touchpad.

Nevertheless, the basic functions of the touchpad work.

I don't know if this is relevant: my notebook is an Acer Aspire E 15 ES1-511-C18C and the Ubuntu version is, as I have said in the title, 14.04.
If I run the app "Mouse and Touchpad", I can see that the device detected is "PS/2 Elantech Touchpad".

```
ajh@ANTONIO-ACER:~$ syndaemon 
ajh@ANTONIO-ACER:~$ killall syndaemon
syndaemon: proceso no encontrado
ajh@ANTONIO-ACER:~$ syndaemon -i 1 -K d
ajh@ANTONIO-ACER:~$ killall syndaemon
syndaemon: proceso no encontrado
ajh@ANTONIO-ACER:~$ syndaemon -i 1 -K -d
ajh@ANTONIO-ACER:~$ killall syndaemon
syndaemon: proceso no encontrado
```

(Note: "Proceso no encontrado" is "process not found" in Spanish).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/299868/disable-touchpad-while-typing-does-not-work

Comment: read more http://www.webupd8.org/2009/11/ubuntu-automatically-disable-touchpad.html

Comment: That doesn't work for me, the touchpad is not disabled while typing. `$killall syndaemon` gives `process not found`. I think that the problem is that ubuntu recognizes the touchpad as a ps2 mouse.

Comment: Because you didn't start it to disable your touchpad. [first start it](http://askubuntu.com/a/462661/283843) then if you want to stop capturing by syndaemon while typing, use `killall syndaemon` to stop it.

Comment: As I have said, `killall syndaemon` gives `syndaemon: process not found`. There's no syndaemons to kill...

Comment: I also said and still say run once `syndaemon` then try to kill it. you want to kill a process while it's not already open. right?

Comment: I have edited the question to add some terminal I/O

Answer (score 8):

First entirely undo the current setting: Remove the tick for Disable touchpad while typing in Mouse & Touchpad settings.

Now search for and open Startup Applications from the Dash. Click Add.

> Name: Syndaemon
>
> Command: syndaemon -i 1.0 -K -R -t
>
> Comment: Disable touchpad while typing, with a reasonable delay and
>   only for tapping and scrolling

The -i 1.0 parameter sets the idle time of the keyboard to 1s. -K option ignores the Modifier keys. -R option uses the XRecord extension for detecting keyboard activity instead of polling the keyboard state. -t option disables tapping and scrolling but not mouse movements.

Click Add and then Close.

Reboot your computer.

Note: this is a user preference, so repeat this in every user account.

Comment: Good solution, but works better for me without the -R option.

Comment: The -t seems to permanently disable tap to click and two finger scrolling permanently.

Comment: This has not worked for me. After a few minutes my touchpad stops responding entirely. Notably I don't have the option to Disable touchpad while typing on ubuntu 15.10

Comment: @zorkerz I'm still having the same problem under Ubuntu 16.04 any luck?

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal window and run:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing
```

It should output:

```
true
```

If it doesn't, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true
```

Alternatively, you can install dconf editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Open dconf-editor and browse to "org" > "gnome" > "settings-deamon" > "peripherals" > "touchpad", and tick "disable-while-typing":

[image]

Comment: I have installed this dconf-editor, and the setting "disable while typing" is *already* enabled. But it doesn't work at all. I can type with the keyboard and click with the touchpad simultaneously.

Comment: @user2425 I am really sorry to hear that, I was hoping the setting in itself would be the problem. is any of the comments helping you?

Comment: Not yet. My problem seems to be that the touchpad is detected as a mouse. I have entered the BIOS Setup and there's no option to change this behaviour.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: I get - "No such schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad'"

Comment: @AlexanderMills The option is removed in 16.04...

Comment: huh, that's weird/annoying is there a way to disable the trackpad while typing in 16.04?

Comment: @AlexanderMills here are some options. I didn't try them: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762189/disable-touchpad-while-typing-option-gone-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts