# "Disable Touchpad while typing option" gone in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: touchpad, 16.04

This option, which was present in the "Mouse and Touchpad" settings panel in previous versions, is for some reason absent in 16.04 LTS. Does anyone know why this is, and/or how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: All the suggestion here don't work for Ubuntu 16.10. As a matter of fact, the solution of @DevNull will disable your trackpad completely. I'm still looking for a solution, but wanted to comment so people are not getting their trackpad disabled.

Comment: @Nitai's comments goes the same for me as of Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: ArchLinux user here: I installed `synaptics` and `xorg-input` and either of these brought the setting back.

Answer (score 14):

I found a [similar question AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773595/how-can-i-disable-touchpad-while-typing-on-ubuntu-16-04-syndaemon-isnt-working) which provided [a link to the details needed to solve this issue](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2316240).

In short, edit your `quirks` file:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-quirks.conf
```

And add the following to the end of the file:

```
# Disable generic Synaptics device, as we're using
# "DLL0704:01 06CB:76AE Touchpad"
# Having multiple touchpad devices running confuses syndaemon
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
        MatchProduct "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

Now restart Xorg:

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```

Now, just start `syndaemon` as usual:

```
killall syndaemon
syndaemon -i 0.50 -m 0.10 -d -K
```

**Note:** For some reason, two-finger scrolling didn't work until I fully rebooted my laptop, but it eventually started working.

## Edit

I eventually installed touchpad indicator like another answer suggests, when I had to switch to a different Dell laptop, and this fix no longer worked.

Answer (score 10):

This works fine for me (ubuntu 16.04):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

Launch `touchpad-indicator`, and go to the **Actions** menu. Select the **Disable the touchpad on typing** option.

<sup>[source](https://www.unixmen.com/autmatically-disable-touchpad-typing-ubuntu/)</sup>

Comment: I've used this, but have found it to be quite unreliable. One major annoyance is the fact that is interprets keyboard shortcuts (such as CTRL+S) as 'typing', meaning every time I save I have to wait half a second before I can use the mouse. 
EDIT: my bad, you need to `killall syndaemon` first.

Comment: worked for me dell latitude 5580

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [DevNull's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/815364/681688), I added this command:

```
syndaemon -i 0.50 -m 0.10 -d -K
```

to my startup application's command. In this way, it still works even after rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

When searching the internet for an answer to this problem, I found a page that suggested using syndaemon to accomplish this (found here: http://www.webupd8.org/2009/11/ubuntu-automatically-disable-touchpad.html). I used the command "syndaemon -i 2 -d -K" in terminal for my needs. This command disables the touchpad while typing for two seconds (-i 2), except when modifier keys such as Alt or Shift are used (-K).

Hope that helps!

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you on?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to change the interval. `syndaemon -i 10 -d -K` still disables for 2 seconds, not 10.

Answer (score 0):

The touchpad settings are gone probably because `libinput` has been installed. It does not have GUI settings.

In Ubuntu 16.10 it is installed by default.

You can either remove `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` or `xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-16.04` to get GUI back, or use a config file for this kind of settings.

Answer (score -1):

In gnome exists an extension that works perfect: 
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/131/touchpad-indicator/

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS uses Unity, and not GNOME Shell, by default. This only works if you've installed `gnome-shell` or `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` or are using the GNOME flavor of Ubuntu.