# Multiple tochpad drivers / disable touchpad while typing

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 19.10, synaptics, xinput

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10 on a ThinkPad T480. After the upgrade I recognized, that my touchpad isn't disabled while typing.

I found this thread ([How can I disable touchpad while typing? On Ubuntu 16.04 syndaemon isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773595/how-can-i-disable-touchpad-while-typing-on-ubuntu-16-04-syndaemon-isnt-working)) and I think, that I have the same problem. I have multiple touchpad drivers installed.

```
$ xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3276-022                      id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated IR Camera: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Is it right, that I have installed two touchpad drivers (Virtual core XTEST pointer and the Synaptics driver)?

I tried to disable one, but it doesn't work:

```
$ sudo xinput -disable 4

X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

How can I remove/disable one driver? How can I configure them, so that my touchpad is disabled while typing?

Answer (score 0):

Every master pointer has a Virtual Core XTEST slave. You need not disable that to disable your touchpad. Instead, you can simply disable the Synaptics one and it should be good enough. In this case,

```
sudo xinput disable 14
```

should do the job.