# How to disable touchpad while typing in 15.10

Tags: 15.04, mouse, touchpad, 15.10

The option for disabling the touchpad while typing does not work in Settings/Mouse & Touchpad in Ubuntu 15.04 (The setting seems to be gone in 15.10??)

I have tried installing 'Pointer Devices' from the software centre, it did not help (settings did not get persisted).

I have seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299868/disable-touchpad-while-typing-does-not-work) and it did not help; I have restarted syndaemon with `syndaemon -i 1 -KRd` and I can still move the mouse while typing.

Is this a bug? Are there any workarounds?

Could this be caused by a tochscreen being present along with a touchpad?

```
~$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN              id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Laptop model is Dell XPS 13 9343

Answer (score 0):

I use **Touchpad-Indicator**, a very flexible app. It is not available from Ubuntu repositories, so you need to add one manually.

- **Latest version**: add the repository with

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao

Then, install as usual:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

To obtain desired option (disable touchpad while typing), Open the program and select that option from Preferences -> Actions.

Don't forget to add the app to the startup list, so this is always enabled. You can do this within the same program, from Preferences -> General options tab.

Now it should work. If it does not work at the beginning, restart the computer/session (some users mention that as an extra step).

If it still does not work, it might be because of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator/+bug/1482039). The workaround is to create an empty configuration file that the program is unable to create itself. This is how (using the terminal):

```
mkdir ~/.config/touchpad-indicator
echo '{}' > ~/.config/touchpad-indicator/touchpad-indicator.conf 
sudo chmod 777 ~/.config/touchpad-indicator/touchpad-indicator.conf
```

Then open the program and configure it again. You can then check that the new configuration variables are inside that file.

- **Older version** (14.04 Trusty, known to work):

If for any reason it still does not work, then try a different version of the program. First, if tried the method above, uninstall it with:

```
`sudo apt-get purge touchpad-indicator`
```

Also, remove ppa with:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atareao-atareao-trusty.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atareao-atareao-trusty.list.save
```

Then, add this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:baltix-members/ppa
```

If you are not using **Trusty**, then you need to change the ppa version. Go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, open the above ppa (called `baltix-members-ppa-trusty.list`) and edit the ubuntu version so that the files contain `trusty` as below:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/baltix-members/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

Then install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. I have installed the app, configured it to disable touchpad when typing, restarted and I can still move the cursor while typing.

Comment: Updated answer with bug info and new ppa.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, but it still does not work :( The `.conf` file was there already, so I skipped creating it and jumped straight to adding ppa:baltix-members. I have removed ppa:atareao though, as I figured it won't be able to find out where to download it from. With this config touchpad-indicator is not found.

Comment: Updated the answer (the ppa has to be set up for Trusty). Also, check that the `.conf` files has the writing rights as required. Run the `chmod` command anyway.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, it has found the new touchpad-indicator in `ppa:baltix-members` now, but it still have not fixed the issue. The file has write priviledges, my settings were saved each time I modified the config. I have also restarted my machine to make sure. I have added extra info to my original question.

Comment: @Zoltan what a shame! I'm sorry it does not work :( There is a similar (and rather old) bug around [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator/+bug/1313239). If you login/sing-up in Launchpad, you can select "Does this bug affect you?", which will bring more importance to the issue. Furthermore, you can send a direct message to the author (which he encourages in his web) using [this form](http://www.atareao.es/contactar/) (mind the Spanish; it's just Name/Email/Subject/Message).