# Touchpad problem: how to disable default syndaemon auto-startup?

Tags: touchpad, 15.10, ubuntu-gnome

I need to prevent autostartup of `syndaemon` because it uses a [bugged option](https://askubuntu.com/a/532886/212172) (`-t`).

Issuing the following two commands does not work:

```
killall syndaemon
syndaemon -i 1 -K -d
```

as the daemon will apparently be restarted by the system resulting in the following (not working) situation:

```
ps -auxf | egrep "syndaemon|USER"
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
nick      1923  0.0  0.0  22364  2584 tty2     S+   11:25   0:00              |   \_ syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R
nick      1930  0.0  0.0  13696  2160 pts/0    S+   11:26   0:00      \_ grep -E --color=auto syndaemon|USER
nick      1904  0.0  0.0  22364   228 ?        Ss   11:25   0:00 syndaemon -i 1 -K -d
```

PS: as strange as it can be, the first time I tried `syndaemon -i 1 -K -d`, it simply worked. However, the problem reappeared after rebooting, and here I am. I saw an update of some GNOME packages.. not sure if they were the cause.

Comment: Answerers might find [Ubuntu bug #1215463](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1215463) relevant here.

Comment: Yes @JdeBP , that is the point. However the problem here is how to *customize* syndaemon: as I describe, Ubuntu Gnome seems to restart automatically the daemon with its default -t option and ignoring the daemon *I* launch!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it in System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad.

Just uncheck "Disable while typing option".

Comment: :-( Too nice to be true: that option has been removed from the GUI since a while. As tagged, I use Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 (driver reasons). Theoretically, that option is now enabled by default, but it is bugged.